# nLockTime transactions, how do they persist? Are they broadcast before they are valid?

Tags: transactions, locktime, mempool

If nLockTime transactions aren't added to the blockchain until the nLockTime is met, then aren't they just being stored in memory of the miners and is there a risk they could get "lost"?

I guess I'm just wondering how a long term nLockTime transaction can really persist. If I set it for 1 year in the future, and everyone restarts their node at some point during that time, isn't there a chance the transaction get's lost? Or would this require all nodes restarting simultaneously?

**EDIT**: Or are nLockTime transactions just held off network by the interested parties and then broadcast once nLockTime is reached? I read some things about DOS attacks with nLockTime transactions leading me to think that miners would not bother storing these at all in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [release notes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/98f4c6c49ce42f3c83d21e5b8ae32eda02a79d49/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.9.0.md) for Bitcoin Core (Satoshi client) version 0.9.0 states

> Accept nLockTime transactions that finalize in the next block

So it will just discard other `nLockTime` transactions. Since most miners run bitcoind or some fork of bitcoind, it is unlikely that an `nLockTime` transaction will persist for a long time.

Comment: In other words: the responsibility of keeping a copy of the transaction and broadcast that when it's time, lies with whoever is interested in making the transaction (probably the recipient)